# Angular force re download script

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

Im trying to force the browser to re download my js script when there is a new version available: I have an `http-inspector` for that:

```
'response': function (response) {
  return $injector.invoke(['$q','$window','$state', function ($q, $window, $state) {
    if (response.status === 205) {
      if (!$state.is('login')){
        $window.location.href = '#/login';
        $window.location.reload();
       }

      return $q.reject(response);
    }

    return response;
  }]);
},
```

When the server returns 205 it means that there is a new script version and i want the user to redownload it

The solution here is working but the problem is that the window is changin and then reload invoke meaning that there is a blink betweet the href and reload.

I tried to use with `$state.go('login', {}, {reload: true})` but this only reload the controller and not the page..

This is a part of the my index.html:

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate" />
.... more head data
</head>
<body>
    <ui-view></ui-view>

    //This is the script i want toreload!
    <script src="my-script.js">
</body>
```

How can i force re download of the script? or how can i avoid that blink?

Comment: To be clear: Your interceptor should trigger the reload of your script on any given request, e.g. you make an API request, the server returns: 'Sorry please load new script version first!', then the reload should happen, correct? Also are your script files loaded dynamically?

Comment: @martinczerwi yes.. every api request can return 205, and not sure i understand the second question.. when you first enter the app `my-scrip` is being download (one time) and if you refresh the page(ctrl+r) the script is being download again.. so i dont think that it is being loaded dynamically (or i completely misunderstood you)

Comment: You understood correctly. I'm not sure if I can help though. What you want is to "hot swap" scripts. I don't know of a solution for it that works with Angulars module system. Maybe you find one.